# How to write the Regular expression for the Below to use in Webdriver?

Tags: xpath, webdriver

I have a requirement for webdriver to use xpath using Regular expression.I have a list of id's with different values.How can i write a expression for the below type of values.

```
//*[@id="js_1"]   
//*[@id="js_2"]    
//*[@id="js_3"]      
//*[@id="js_4"]   
//*[@id="js_5"]    
//*[@id="js_6"]
```

I have to write the regrular expression for that above xpath format using webdriver?
I have tried with the below

Listnames=box.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'js_*')]"));

But it wont work for me.How can i write a expression.Please help me.

Thanks & Regards,
Shiva Oleti

Answer (score 5):

If you use `js_*` as standard regular expression it matches `js, js_, js__, js___` ...

The correct regular expression would be `js_\d+`

However, the XPath contains function does not use regular expressions, so you can just use `js_` (although it won't check for numbers).

Or better

```
`//div[starts-with(@id, 'js_')]`
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Webdriver supports XQuery (such as using XQUIB), therefore full XPath 2.0 is supported.

**Use**:

```
//*[matches(@id, '^js_\d+$')]
```

**XSLT-2.0 - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:sequence select="//*[matches(@id, '^js_\d+$')]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>
 <x id="js_1"/>
 <y id="a1"/>
 <z id="js_2008"/>
</t>
```

**the above XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
<x id="js_1"/>
<z id="js_2008"/>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the XPath 2.0 function **[`matches()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-matches)** and **[RegEx](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#regex-syntax)**.

Answer (score -1):

Else you can use a loop to add elements to your list ...

```
List <WebElement> ls = null;
i=1;
while(i<5)
{
ls.add(we.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/section/nav/div[2]/ul/li["+i+
 "]")));
 i++;
 }
```